# How to create a video that can be uploaded to Twitter in Mac?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, mac, imovie

I'm using Mac to make videos.

I have iMovie and Final Cut Pro.

It seems that the videos that can be uploaded to Twitter have a specific formats.

Does anyone know what's the easiest way to make such a video in Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Twitter's support page](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-videos):

> We currently support MP4 and MOV video formats on mobile apps.
>
> On the web, we support the MP4 video format with H264 format with AAC
> audio. You can upload videos up to 512MB, however you will be prompted
> to edit videos to 2 minutes and 20 seconds or less in length.

You can [export an h264 format video directly from Final Cut](https://www.rocketstock.com/blog/how-to-export-video-in-final-cut-pro/).